# How do I access HttpContext from an abstract base Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, initialization, httpcontext

I have created an abstract controller class (`ApplicationController`) for handling some user authentication, but `HttpContext` is not initialized when the code get called.

```
public abstract class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    public ApplicationController()        
    {
        string myuser = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name; // NullReferenceException
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yassir is correct about using protected constructors in abstract classes. But you are correct that it doesn't solve your problem--the HttpContext still ain't quite populated yet so you get null reference exceptions.

Anyhow, the solution is simple--override the Initialize method of the controller:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    string myuser = this.User.Identity.Name;
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to make your .ctor protected

```
public abstract class ApplicationController : Controller 
{
    protected ApplicationController()
    {
        string myuser = this.User.Identity.Name;
    } 
}
```

also make sure you are not missing this using directive:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

Comment: what difference does it make if the ctor is made protected?